# What are the possibillities to get overall CPU percentage usage

Tags: uwp, cpu

I have the following question:

In UWP, how can we get an overall CPU percentage usage, RAM usage,free RAM, Running process, etc? It's required for task manager in UWP.

Comment: So of those things you can get [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37850354/2681948).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi after doing some looking it doesn't seem as if you can get the device CPU, RAM and Free Ram or the Running Processes. 
You can get the CPU, memory as well as the memory limits for an application.

You can get these through the following ways:

**RAM**:
This is accessed through the [MemoryManager Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.system.memorymanager.aspx)

```
MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsage
```

And there are some other static members that will help you.

**CPU**: As for CPU this is retrieved using - [Windows.System.Diagnostics.ProcessCpuUsage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.diagnostics.processcpuusage.aspx)

Comment: ProcessDiagnosticInfo.GetForCurrentProcess.CpuUsage.GetReport() returns UserTime and KernelTime as in cpu time, not percentage. How do you calculate them into cpu usage percentage?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the total system memory and CPU usage with the [SystemDiagnosticInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.diagnostics.systemdiagnosticinfo?view=winrt-20348) class.

```cs
var diagnosticInfo = SystemDiagnosticInfo.GetForCurrentSystem();

// Total physical RAM
ulong totalMemory = diagnosticInfo.MemoryUsage.GetReport().TotalPhysicalSizeInBytes;

var cpuUsage = diagnosticInfo.CpuUsage.GetReport();
// Total kernel/user/idle time since system start
var kernelTime = cpuUsage.KernelTime
var userTime = cpuUsage.UserTime
var idleTime = cpuUsage.IdleTime
```

To get CPU usage as a percentage, you need to take measurements at two different points in time (e.g. 100ms apart), then calculate (deltaKernelTime + deltaUserTime) / (deltaKernelTime + deltaUserTime + deltaIdleTime).