# Get CPU, RAM and GPU information - UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

Is possible get the information of the CPU, GPU and RAM of a computer, in a UWP app? E show this information in a textblock.

I want to know the processor model (for example: Intel Core i7 xxxx), and total RAM

Comment: Your answer is here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959610/what-are-the-possibillities-to-get-overall-cpu-percentage-usage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the possibillities to get overall CPU percentage usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959610/what-are-the-possibillities-to-get-overall-cpu-percentage-usage)

Comment: @Kaikon I did not explain myself well, I want to know the processor model (for example: Intel Core i7 xxxx), and total RAM and GPU (for exemple: NVidia GTxxxx)

Comment: @pmcilreavy I did not explain myself well, I want to know the processor model (for example: Intel Core i7 xxxx), and total RAM and GPU (for exemple: NVidia GTxxxx)

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know the processor model (for example: Intel Core i7 xxxx), and total RAM

If in this case, UWP app cannot meet your demands. In UWP you can not get the system CPU , GPU and RAM information since it is sandbox.

For RAM, UWP can only access to information on current app's memory usage by using the `MemoryManager` class as the comment mentioned.

For GPU information, currently there is no API can access GPU directly in UWP app. You may need to create a UWP app with DirectX and access the information by DirectX. You may find some relative samples [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples).

Since Win32 could do this, as a suggestion, you could try to use [Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root) to convert the Win32 desktop app to UWP. For how to get these information in Win32 you could reference [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root).

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use [DllImport("kernal32")] for the full info. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105031/how-do-you-get-total-amount-of-ram-the-computer-has) has the implementation you need. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959610/what-are-the-possibillities-to-get-overall-cpu-percentage-usage) answers how to get the RAM usage and CPU usage much easier.

Comment: I did not explain myself well, I want to know the processor model (for example: Intel Core i7 xxxx), and total RAM and GPU (for exemple: NVidia GTxxxx)

Answer (score 0):

You can get at least some device information which includes CPU model using following code. It will include lot of devices and one of them is CPU.

```
string result = "Devices\r\n";

DeviceInformationCollection dic = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.All);

foreach (var deviceinfo in dic)
{
    result += "\r\nID: " + deviceinfo.Id + ", Name: " + deviceinfo.Name + ", Kind: " + deviceinfo.Kind + ", EnclosureLocation: " + deviceinfo.EnclosureLocation + ", IsEnabled: " + deviceinfo.IsEnabled;
}
```