# How to get system information in a uwp aplication?

Tags: uwp

Im able to get some information like :
device family - Windows.Desktop
System Version -10.0.17134.471
System Architecture - X86
Device Mnaufacturer - LENOVO
Device Model - 2436CTO
But I need information related to memory and how to attain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Windows Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/systeminformation)
So please take a look at [SystemInformation Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.helpers.systeminformation?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable&viewFallbackFrom=uwp-toolkit-dotnet)

- Sample project on github [UWP-SystemInfoCollector](https://github.com/validvoid/UWP-SystemInfoCollector)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but i need to know how to get CPU related information.

Comment: Did you mean Cpu usage and etc ? [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.diagnostics)  Or This thread [Get CPU, RAM and GPU information - UWP App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48194014/get-cpu-ram-and-gpu-information-uwp-app)