# Specs of computer

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

In a UWP application, developed in C#, how can I get information about the computer's specifications (CPU, GPU, RAM and HDD / SSD)?

For example:

- CPU: Intel Core i7 xxxx
- RAM: 8GB
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce xxx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get pc (system) information on windows machine - C# script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742389/get-pc-system-information-on-windows-machine-c-sharp-script)

Comment: @WaynePhipps but does this also work for UWP applications?

Comment: This does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54195953/how-to-get-system-information-in-a-uwp-aplication also referenced here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/systeminformation

Comment: @WaynePhipps I already use this in my application, but it does not give me the information I want (CPU, GPU, storage, etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get system information in a uwp aplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54195953/how-to-get-system-information-in-a-uwp-aplication)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently no public API allowing you to gather the hardware information of the device.

For CPU you can get it usage [using `SystemCpuUsage` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.diagnostics.systemcpuusage).

For information about memory usage [try `MemoryManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.memorymanager).

Finally, you might be able to get some GPU info [via DirectX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090261/get-the-graphics-card-model).